# how to add arguments in python3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments

How can i add system arguments in python3.7?
Im trying to make an IP finder and i want the syntax to be like this:

```
python3 ipfind.py -u www.google.com
```

and it prints the google ip.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use argparse or OptionParser. Please see the documentation for the OptionParser at the following URL:

[OptionParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/optparse.html)

Here is the simple code to get the IP of a given URL.

```
''' Simple program to return the IP.
You need to add lot more exception handling. 
''' 
import socket
from optparse import OptionParser

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-u", "--url", dest="url",
              help="specify url to find the IP", action="store")

(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

try:
    if options.url:
        ip = socket.gethostbyname(options.url)
        print("URL: %s IP: %s" %(options.url, ip))
except:
    print("Unable to get IP address for URL %s" %(options.url))
    raise
```

A sample run:

```
$python test3.py -u google.com
URL: google.com IP: 172.217.8.14
```